# Can we substitute a function name with variable in C#

Tags: function, c#-4.0

I wanted to check if we can create a function name from variable value in C#. Here is what I am trying. I have a list of strings as below:

```
private List<string> _pages;
_pages.AddRange(new string[] { "Page1", "Page2", "Page3", "Page4"});
```

And I have tasks like below:

```
private async void Sync_Page1() {}
private async void Sync_Page2() {}
private async void Sync_Page3() {}
private async void Sync_Page4() {}
```

For each of those strings in the list, I need to call a method like below

```
foreach (string pageName in _pages)
{
    Task.Run(async () => { Sync_pageName() }); // where pageName will be the items from list.  
}
```

Tried searching on google but didn't find anything specific. So not sure if that can be done in C# but was wondering if there is a possibility.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can map it to dictionary items which you can invoke :

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
 
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            PagesExecution pe = new PagesExecution();
            pe.Execute();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
 
    public class PagesExecution
    {
        //Action<string> a = new Action<string>();

        private List<string> _pages = new List<string>();
        private Dictionary<string,  Action> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
        public PagesExecution ()
        {
        }

        public void Execute()
        {               
            dictionary.Add("Page1", new Action(Sync_Page1));
            dictionary.Add("Page2", Sync_Page2);
            dictionary.Add("Page3", Sync_Page3);
            dictionary.Add("Page4", Sync_Page4);

           _pages.AddRange(new string[] { "Page1", "Page2", "Page3", "Page4"});

            foreach (var entry in _pages)
            {
                dictionary[entry].Invoke();
            }
        }

        
        public void   Sync_Page1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Page1");
        }
        private void Sync_Page2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Page2");
        }
        private void Sync_Page3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Page3");
        }
        private void Sync_Page4()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Page4");
        }

    }
}
```